# How to use OAUTH with gapi client library for Google Cloud Endpoints and Google Cloud Storage at the same time

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints, google-api-client

For my current project i want to use Cloud Endpoints and Cloud Storage API at the same time.

When you authenticate for cloud endpoints the example tic-tac-toe app from Google states that one should set the access_token to be the id_token like this (see [github repository](http://goo.gl/gh3wpK)):

```
var token = gapi.auth.getToken();
// Use id_token instead of bearer token
token.access_token = token.id_token;
```

However once the access_token is set to the id_token one cannot use the other google apis anymore. In my case the Cloud Storage API. The reason for this is that the access token is now invalid for them. For example, the cloud storage api returns **Invalid credential**.
Before the access_token is set to the id_token, the access_token looks like this: `ya29.AHES6ZTjklghkljghlkjfghkljsrdölizuklhlfghI_UTfghdfghCg`. It gets replaced with the id_token that i don't want to post here because it's really long.

The two solutions that i can think of are:

- Copy the gapi object, each with a separate auth-object and token. Use the one with the id_token for cloud endpoints and the other for the rest (i was unable to copy the object in a way that makes this possible though)
- Remember the auth token somewhere and replace it depending on what api (cloud endpoints / other api) i call (this would probably need synchronization and is somewhat messy)

I'm very interested in solutions and feasible workarounds for this problem.

If you encounter this issue, please read the answer below and my comments. Once you've done that you'll understand that this question is actually more this question here: [How do I test Cloud Endpoints with Oauth on devserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117695/how-do-i-test-cloud-endpoints-with-oauth-on-devserver)

I'll leave the question here in case someone searches for the terms inside.

Comment: Are you using the `gapi.auth.authorize` function? If so, you can use the `scope` parameter to scope your token to multiple APIs.

Comment: Yes, i do use `gapi.auth.authorize` with the two scopes for userinfo.email and cloud storage. The authorize function calls the callback which does `gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(function(resp) {
  if (!resp.code) {
   var token = gapi.auth.getToken();
   token.access_token = token.id_token;
   gapi.auth.setToken(token);`
but when the access_token is set to the id_token, the storage api gives me the Invalid credential error whereas clound enpoints work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python Tic Tac Toe sample appears to be in need of an update. ID tokens are no longer required in this particular case. (The [Java example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-java/blob/master/war/js/base.js) is using Google+ login, so it has slightly different requirements.)

You can leave out manipulation of the token, and it will automatically work for Endpoints and whatever other Google API you are calling. See the [Python "Hello Endpoints" example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-python/blob/master/static/js/base.js) for what this looks like (most notable for what isn't in it).

Comment: I will try that. What i saw yesterday was that, when the access_token is not the id_token, the cloud endpoints are not working anymore - but i might have something wrong in there. The new python example looks better, i wonder if i have to upgrade the App Engine SDK for it.

Comment: You are right. We do not have to replace the access_token with the id_token. The issue, as i found out now, is: If i do not use the id_token, then user.getEmail() returns example@example.com. And for that there is already an open stack overflow question, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117695/how-do-i-test-cloud-endpoints-with-oauth-on-devserver